# Sending multidimensional array via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So basically here is my jQuery and HTML code for creating arrays. It basically takes each div with class setting and checks wether it has span with attribute rel, if it has, it inserts in array under array. Each new div.settign span rel attributes will be inserted to another array under same parent array.

Check this code to understand it - http://jsfiddle.net/xVuHx/ .

Pasted it also here -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var rel = [];
    jQuery(".setting").each(function() {
        rel.push(jQuery(this).find('span[rel]').map(function() {
            return this.getAttribute('rel');
        }).get());
    });               
    jQuery("body").text(rel);
});​
```

and html -

```
<div class="setting">
    <span rel="Variable">Variable</span>
    <span rel="Item">Item</span>
    <span rel="Something">Something</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span rel="Smth">Smth</span>
    <span>Sec</span>
</div>
<div class="setting">
    <span>Second</span>
    <span rel="first">First</span>
    <span rel="Third">Third</span>
</div>
```

it's working great and displays two arrays - one with 3 elements and one with two, but when I try to pass it to PHP file via ajax, ti gives me [object Object] with var_dump($array); . Also I tried to do foreach, but it told me that invalid arguments were passed to foreach statement, so I guess I'm sending the array to ajax incorrectly or the Array is made incorrectly.

Here is my ajax code -

```
var myArray = jQuery(this).sortable("serialize") + "&type="+rel+"&action=update_homepage";
jQuery.post("'.admin_url("admin-ajax.php").'", myArray, function(response){
   var info = response.slice(0,-1);
});
```

This ajax code is made via wordpress, so its ajax requests differs a little bit from default AJAX requests.

Could you please check what exactly could be the problem?

**EDIT:**

Just tried to output with `print_r($myArray);` in php side, it outputs empty string.

Comment: perhaps try print_r($array) to see output?  I have to run now or would try to help but perhaps that gets you going.  Good luck!

Comment: print_r() doesn't output anything (empty space).

Comment: sounds like empty object then so not being set.  I do see you are serializing some content, but then you append a querystring to it.  seems your array would be broken in that case?

Comment: you are setting myArray in Javascript but then trying to read it with PHP?  PHP will not be able to read the value of the Javascript variable.  It is 2am for me so perhaps I'm fuzzy, but that's what it looks like you're trying to do and doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Tried to pass it without serialize, but it still is the same.

Comment: Not sure, why it's not possible to pass JS arrays to PHP with ajax :). Have passed it already, but haven't passed multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check format of posted data in AJAX request in browser console (section network).

You can find information about opening the console in your browser in [this stackexchange question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

[JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) - JSON in JavaScript.

To convert an object to JSON, use `JSON.stringify`:

```
var json_text = JSON.stringify(your_object, null, 2);
```

Encode your array to JSON and then send it with Ajax request. To decode JSON in PHP use [json_decode](http://us.php.net/json_decode)

Comment: It returns two inputs, if i do json_cedore(..., true); it doesn't display anything after that.

Answer (score 0):

it would be better to convert it in to json

Comment: Forgot to mention that I tried to pass it with JSON also, but it returned empty space also.